# Negation of sameness is confirmation of difference

Tags: programming-practices, coding-style, terminology, language-agnostic

[De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws):

- the negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of the negations; and
- the negation of a conjunction is the disjunction of the negations;

or, the same:

- not (A or B) = not A and not B; and
- not (A and B) = not A or not B;

or, the same, applied to the programming:

- `If !(Var1 || Var2)` = `If (!Var1 && !Var2)`
- `If !(Var1 && Var2)` = `If (!Var1 || !Var2)`

In the programming we have one another case, and I'm not sure this case is a part of these laws:

- the negation of the sameness is the confirmation of the difference. (I'm not sure the wording is good enough.)

  `If !(Var1 = Var2)` = `If (Var1 != Var2)`

Does it have some name which could be used e.g. in style guides?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PyCharm calls it

> Negate '!=' to '=='

And it makes more sense for a style guide because if you come up with really correct definition from mathematics, it may be less understandable.

The style guide then may proclaim:

"As a rule, negate '!=' to '=' in all conditions"

It can probably also be put as words: "Negate inequality to equality [operator]".

Answer (score 0):

From a logical point of view, the predicate:

```
if a=b then a and b are the same
```

is equivalent to its [contrapostive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition):

```
 if a and b are different then a!=b
```

When considering this logical point of view, you can see that the negation of a=b is not necessarily a!=b (it can and it often is but it hasn’t have to be).

From a practical point of view, The operator `=` and the operator `!=` are two different operators.  So it depends on the semantics of the language and the guarantees given for these operators. And for languages that allow overloads, it also depends on the design of the overloads of these operators if overloads are allowed. Finally it also depends on what meaning you give to “same”.

For example, if a language would use object references, and if `A=B` would mean that the obect references are equal, then `A!=B` could just mean that it’s two different objects, even if the two objects could be of exactly the same value.

In other languages, you could have the case that a concrete type provides an implementation for `operator=` and `operator=!` is not implemented. In this case   `A=B` would compile for two objects of this type whereas `A!=B` would fail to compile.

*Note: in some languages `=` has a different semantics than `==`*